# Is it possible to make a transaction with my own account?

Tags: extrinsic, transactions, subxt

I'm currently trying to make a transaction using subxt tool.

I could generate tx with test sr25519 keyring (Alice, Bob, ...), but I'm not sure I can do this with my account on rococo testnet.

I made my account and got a faucet for testing, but I'm stuck making PairSigner.

From this example https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/balance_transfer.rs, I'm trying to make a signer with the account.

I've searched all possible ways (from_string, from_phrase, ...) but they didn't work for me. (Maybe I misused them)

Below code is my example to make a signer. (account_seed is 12 words seed)

```
let pair = crypto::Pair::from_string(&config.account_seed, Some(&config.account_password)).unwrap();
let signer = PairSigner::new(pair);
```

Thank you for any advice or solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [How to generate a new account with seed using rust?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/how-to-generate-a-new-account-with-seed-using-rust), which talks about generating a new `Pair` from a seed.

When that's been generated, you can do `let signer = PairSigner::new(pair);` as you have done to make use of it in Subxt!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use `from_seed` or `from_seed_slice`.

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_core/crypto/trait.Pair.html#tymethod.from_seed

1. `from_seed` takes a `[u8; 32]`.
2. `from_seed_slice` takes a `&[u8]` (but you should make sure it is 32 bytes-length).

The seed is the private key to your account.

Let's use subkey:

```rs
subkey generate
Secret phrase:       palm clinic heavy fat saddle trophy right twenty deputy deal cotton enact
  Network ID:        substrate
  Secret seed:       0x9e963df48eb2aeb329ff7a03991ac20a93130e619130a8431ce02bbee2b0a4ea
  Public key (hex):  0xe64810dc55abb26dafcca141c4766f87a0fa532e0a18beac1dc7290d2c3dd57e
  Account ID:        0xe64810dc55abb26dafcca141c4766f87a0fa532e0a18beac1dc7290d2c3dd57e
  Public key (SS58): 5HGeH7iX1xqiRm5tsgyz1uU6haS2VqvstGJfj15p4fWduyN3
  SS58 Address:      5HGeH7iX1xqiRm5tsgyz1uU6haS2VqvstGJfj15p4fWduyN3
```

`0x9e963df48eb2aeb329ff7a03991ac20a93130e619130a8431ce02bbee2b0a4ea` is what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues, I got a compiling implementation after a long time of searching for an example using a hex-encoded seed.

I posted it as an answer to another issue [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/8101/3989), but what I did was simply use the re-exported structs from `subxt` as seen below:

```
use subxt::ext::sp_core::Pair;
use subxt::tx::PairSigner;

...

pub async fn something() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {

...

    let pair = subxt::ext::sp_core::sr25519::Pair::from_string_with_seed(<'0x'-PREFIXED PRIVATE SEED>, Some(<PASSWORD>)).unwrap();
    let signer: PairSigner<SubstrateConfig, subxt::ext::sp_core::sr25519::Pair> = PairSigner::<SubstrateConfig, subxt::ext::sp_core::sr25519::Pair>::new(pair.0);

...
}
```