# Error Metadata(IncompatibleCodegen) - subxt

Tags: extrinsic, subxt

I was executing a transaction using Alice account to make a sudo call in local Rococo Network

```rs
let alice = PairSigner::new(AccountKeyring::Alice.pair())
```

I am trying to change it to use my own account following this previous answers on StackExchange in: [Is it possible to make a transaction with my own account?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/is-it-possible-to-make-a-transaction-with-my-own-account).
To test it I got the Alice's keys from: [What are the predefined accounts (ALICE, BOB, etc)?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-are-the-predefined-accounts-alice-bob-etc)

```rs
let mnemonic_phrase = std::env::var("SEED").expect("Error: No mnemonic phrase");
let pair = sp_core::sr25519::Pair::from_string(&mnemonic_phrase, None).unwrap();
let alice = PairSigner::new(pair);

println!("pair: {:?}", pair.public());
```

It looks like is recovering Alice account fine, but when I try to execute the extrinsic I am getting an error: `Error: Metadata(IncompatibleCodegen)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run into an `Metadata(IncompatibleCodegen)`, it means that the metadata used to generate the static interface (either via the `subxt` macro or `subxt codegen` CLI tool) is out of date (or otherwise different) from the metadata of the node you're trying to talk to.

The error basically means "the interface has changed, and so your code needs to be updated". In this case, the thing to do is download new metadata from the node, and then fix any compilation errors that crop up as a result of the interface changes :)

Comment: To get the metadata of the local network, is without --uri? subxt metadata -f bytes >  metadata/local_metadata.scale

Comment: Yup, no `--url` means it'll default to the local node at the moment (or you can provide an explicit url eg `--url ws://127.0.0.1:9944`).